# How to make annotation deprecated only on one target

Tags: java, annotations, deprecated

I have an annotation that can be added on `METHOD` and `TYPE` and is used in thousands of places in our project.

```
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Inherited
public @interface RequiredStore{
    Store value();
}
```

Is it possible to make the annotation deprecated only on methods while keeping it non-deprecated on types? I want other developers to be notified by IDE that it should not be used on methods any more, until we'll refactor all existing usages and finally remove the `METHOD` part.

If it's not possible, is there any Way to handle such case beside creating new annotation only for types and deprecating the old one?

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it other than what you have already suggested.

Comment: You might be able to write some kind of custom inspection for an IDE, what IDEs do the other developers use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an annotation [Processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html).

For example, the annotation and its processor would be placed in its own `.jar` file and added as a dependency of the sources that use the annotation.

The custom `.jar` would have the following structure:

```
src/main/
    java/com/company/annotations/
        RequiredStore.java
        RequiredStoreProcessor.java
    resources/META-INF/services
        javax.annotation.processing.Processor
```

`RequiredStore.java` stays as you have it above.

`RequiredStoreProcessor.java` could look something like this:

```
package com.company.annotations;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.company.annotations.RequiredStore")
public class RequiredStoreProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(
            Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element 
                : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(RequiredStore.class)) {
            if (element.getKind().equals(ElementKind.METHOD)) {
                processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                    Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING,
                    "Using @RequiredStore on methods has been deprecated\n"
                        + "Class: " + element.getEnclosingElement() + "\n"
                        + "Method: " + element.getSimpleName() + "\n");
            }
        }

        // Other processing...

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latest();
    }
}
```

The `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file allows `javac` to pickup the Processor via SPI and simply contains

```
com.company.annotations.RequiredStoreProcessor
```

Finally, compile this into a `.jar` and add it to the classpath where the annotations are being used. Any methods that have the `@RequiredStore` will produce a compiler warning. For example, for this class,

```
package com.company.business;

import com.company.annotations.RequiredStore;

@RequiredStore
public interface Business {
    @RequiredStore
    public void someMethod();
}
```

The compiler warning would be this:

```
warning: Using @RequiredStore on methods has been deprecated
  Class: com.company.business.Business
  Method: someMethod
```

As for an indication in the IDE, you might have to write a custom inspection and unfortunately this depends on the IDE used.

---

### Notes:

Decent custom annotations reference: [Code Generation using Annotation Processors in the Java language](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/)

Comment: I just came back to say "you could detect it at run time (although not at compile time)" and you beat me to it :)

Comment: It's not an answer to the requirement (which is to make the IDE report it), but I give it a +1 just for being a really cool and useful answer. I didn't even know you could do this!

Comment: @Gimby yeah, IDEs won't flag compiler warnings/errors of custom annotations AFAIK, which is unfortunate. But I think you could combine the above with a custom IntelliJ inspection or Eclipse equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay about using native aspectj, another option is to use AspectJ's code enforcement policy this way:

```
public aspect RequiredStoreAnnotationCheck {

    declare warning: execution(@RequiredStore * *.*(..)) : "Required store annotation not    appropriate for methods..";

}
```

If the IDE is integrated with AspectJ, this would be flagged as a compile time check.

AspectJ in action book has a good amount of detail on this too.

Here is one of my blog articles for more context: http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/03/code-policy-enforcement-using-aspectj.html